# Visual Studio code run Junit from UI?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a maven project (archtype quicksetup).
And I have a testcases annotated with @Test.

Is it possible to run the unit test from the Visual Studio Code UI ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft finally released an extension for this exact purpose. However the documentation at this point is definitly lacking. I myself did not get it to work up to this point.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/12/01/announcing-junit-support-for-visual-studio-code/